# Not able to configure SSO, error: "Enter a valid url for AssertionConsumerService"

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I am trying to configure SSO for Jfrog artifactory version 6.16.0. I have saved below Service Provider metadata in a xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns2:EntityDescriptor xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://example.com/artifactory">                         
    <ns2:SPSSODescriptor WantAssertionsSigned="true" AuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <ns2:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</ns2:NameIDFormat>
        <ns2:AssertionConsumerService index="1" Location="http://example.com/webapp/saml/loginResponse" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
    </ns2:SPSSODescriptor>
</ns2:EntityDescriptor>
```

When I am uploading this file in IDP server getting the error:

> Enter a valid url for AssertionConsumerService

Comment: Have you actually modified the AssertionConsumerService Location and entityID values with you own Artifactory URL instead of the `http://example.com/webapp/...`? also, which IDP you are using?

Comment: Maybe you are missing '/artifactory' in the url? http://example.com/webapp/saml/loginResponse --> http://example.com/artifactory/webapp/saml/loginResponse